# HQL weird behaviour

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am facing a very weird problem with hibernate
Let's say I'm fetching data from two tables TableA and TableB(tables are not having any mapping relationship in the POJO)

Here's my HQL query:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3.name, b.col4.name FROM TableA a, TableB b WHERE a.fkCol = b.pkCol
```

Now what actually is happening is all the data for which b.col3 and b.col4 is NULL, that data is not fetched.

NOTE : TableB contains two foreign keys(col3 and col4)(ie. reference to some other POJO TableC and TableD)

Comment: b.col3.name is an implicit **inner** join. You want a **left** join. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-implicit-join

Comment: is there any way to change that implicit inner join to left join.?

Comment: Sure. Why don't you read the documentation I linked to? That's what it's for. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: I have gone through the provided documentation, but in my case, I need TableB to be left joined with two tables(TableC and TableD). Is it possible to do so using HQL.?

Comment: Well, use two left joins.

Comment: yes I tried and it worked...thanks